# pidgin: how to make it log logins/logouts of an ICQ buddy if the conversation tab is still open

Tags: login, logging, pidgin, logout

when pidgin was called gaim and you had opened a tab with am ICQ buddy, all his logins and logouts were logged during the time you had that tab open. It didnt' even matter if your buddy was online before you opened the tab with him.

In pidgin 2.6.6, I this behavior can no longer be observed and I cannot find an option in the preferences or buddy context menu to enable it.

How do I restore that behavior from gaim time?

Thanks!

Comment: The newest version is 2.7.3 now, give it a try. It work for me with MSN, so it should work with ICQ too.

Answer (score 1):

update to the latest version of pidgin available and go to preferences -> loging -> log all status changes to system log